# Obtaining the iPad Screen display at a lower resolution with createScreenIOSurface

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, iphone-privateapi

I have been working on screen capture on iOS devices and system level API's like IOSurface, IOMobileFramebuffer etc. both out of interest and need. In extension to the answer mentioned in [Creating an image out of the ios surface and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872728/creating-an-image-out-of-the-ios-surface-and-saving-it) by Victor Ronnin, I had a question. As mentioned there, createScreenIOSurface API indeed works and provides the screen surface/ video buffer for use.

The new iPad (on which I am working) has a resolution of 2048 X 1536 and hence, createScreenIOSurface takes significant time. I had experimented a bit and found that these surfaces indeed support 1024 X 768 resolution (probably scaling happens and it happens real quick), so, with IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface, you can obtain the screen surface at 1024 X 768 resolution and very quick. My question is there any analogous argument to createScreenIOSurface to obtain the surface at lower resolution ? Also, any inputs on how 1024 X 768 is supported by these displays would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343606/how-can-i-record-the-screen-with-acceptable-performance-while-keeping-the-ui-res

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but it's information in the area, which are you are researching.