# Screenshot out of my app ios 10

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

I want to screenshot display out of my app when an event occurred.
I read these links( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971013/taking-screenshots-in-the-background-ios-improving-performance), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872728/creating-an-image-out-of-the-ios-surface-and-saving-it/13908150#13908150), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872728/creating-an-image-out-of-the-ios-surface-and-saving-it/13885700#13885700)) but they aren't for ios 10. I want to know if I can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

extension UIView {

```
public func toImage () -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0.0)
    drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks IOS Developer but what I want is to take screenshot from display not to alert when user takes screenshot.

Comment: I have edit the answer for take a screenshot of any view with uiview extension