# Taking Screenshots in the background (iOS) - Improving Performance

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, screenshot, iphone-privateapi

This question is an extension of: [Taking Screenshots from iOS app - emulating Display recorder (query on the internals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833816/taking-screenshots-from-ios-app-emulating-display-recorder-query-on-the-inter)
There are 2 ways, I came across to take screenshots from the background -

1. [Creating an image out of the ios surface and saving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872728/creating-an-image-out-of-the-ios-surface-and-saving-it) - it captures at a very fast rate (approximately 0.2-0.3 sec/ 12-15 screenshots), however there are some problems that are encountered, discussed here: [Releasing an IOSurface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952313/releasing-an-iosurface)
2. The following code does the same job using the createScreenIOSurface API:

   IOSurfaceRef surface = [UIWindow createScreenIOSurface];
   UIImage *surfaceImage = [[UIImage alloc] _initWithIOSurface:surface orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
   CFRelease(surface);
   UIImageSaveToPhotosAlbum(surfaceImage, self, nil, nil);

However, the capture rate is very bad, approximately 0.5-0.7 sec/screenshot.

So, is there a solution to the problem faced in approach 1 ? 
Is there a way to improve performance for approach 2 ?

Comment: Please don't make us go to pastie.org to look at your code.  You can post it right into your question here, and format it with the little **{ }** button.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought it would only increase the length of the question. I will post the code here itself.

Comment: Any update to this topic plz?