# How to include IOSurfaceRef

Tags: iphone-privateapi, iosurface

I'm attempting to create an app using private APIs to take screenshots from the background.  I found this example:  [Taking Screenshots in the background (iOS) - Improving Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971013/taking-screenshots-in-the-background-ios-improving-performance)

In the author's code, the first line makes use of the IOSurfaceRef type.  Can somebody explain to me how to include this in my code?  I attempted to link IOSurfaceAPI.h (where I thought IOSurfaceRef was defined), however that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

**First lets start by how to link the Frameworks**

1. go to https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/tree/master/IOSurface and download the headers
2. the **IOSurfaceAPI.h** files is not included with the download link "due to legal reasons" link and you have to copy it from Xcode from here

   change **MacOSX10.11.sdk** in the path according to the sdk included with Xcode

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/**MacOSX10.11.sdk**/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/Headers

2. go to */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework*
   and create a folder named **Headers**

> replace **iPhoneOS.platform** with **iPhoneSimulator.platform** an paste the headers in simulator SDK folder too if you want to try apps on the simulator

4. paste all files inside

> Now you can use the IOSurface Framework

Comment: Great, so does IOSurface framework work on iPhone device now?

Comment: But to link to it you need to create those .tbd files

Comment: Can you please provide me links for these... I will really appreciate your help...

Comment: You can look at existing once: **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork.tbd**

Comment: I am confused... do we have to create IOSurface.tbd file? I think, they removed IOSurface.framework from above PrivateFrameworks folders long time back. Even then can we use the old IOSurface API to capture system wide screen from background?

Comment: Yes you need to create it inside **IOSurface.framework**

Comment: How to create tbd file? Is it from old executable file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136655/discussion-between-trident-and-karim).

Comment: Can you create a tbd file for IOMobileFramebuffer too?

Comment: No, it is still not working, none of the API's i know in IOSurface framework are working to get display capture. Please help with the API too..

Comment: As far as i know, IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface fails on iOS 10, can you make a sample tbd with this API alone? I will check it

Comment: How fails, crash?

Comment: No, the method fails with return code -536870201. I think, Apple removed the API.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137189/discussion-between-karim-and-trident).